# Android Firebase value listener no longer works after DB change

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Was creating an application on one Firebase project, and now that it's complete I've changed it to another Firebase project which has the actual database (same structure, the first project was for testing, the second is the actual live database we're using). Changed it by creating the Android version in the Firebase console, and then putting in the new google-services.json file. Now, a certain bit of code that was working perfectly now refuses to do anything whatsoever, and I don't understand why. All I have done to change the code is change the Firebase Storage references, which do not affect this particular bit of code. The database structures are identical and both databases have data at that particular path. Here is the code that is affected. This code is perfectly functional on the old database, but on the new database the onDataChange method is not called whatsoever, nor is the onCancelled. Is there anything stupid I am missing that would cause this not to work? I have been able to access functions on the new database and have successfully registered an account on the new database from the application, so am puzzled as to why this doesn't work.

```
public void checkForOtherAgent() {
    agentcode = branchNo + postcode;
    count = 0;
    codeCheckListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange called, count = " + count);
                count++;
                agentcode = branchNo + postcode + count;
                mDatabase.child("agent_codes").child(agentcode).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(codeCheckListener);
            } else {
                registerAccount();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    mDatabase.child("agent_codes").child(agentcode).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(codeCheckListener);
}
```

Comment: check the realtime database rules from the console, is it already the same with your previous project? if it violates the rules, you should see a warning message in the logcat everytime the valueEventListener is attached.

Comment: I wasn't receiving the warning message at first but when trying out the DB change again on a backup copy I then received the permission denied logcat warning. Sure enough, the DB rules had been changed to require auth for that particular branch, and this was called prior to signup and therefore auth!

Comment: you can change the rules to `".write":true,".read":true` to test the database before release